# Intended way to add a new spring-securty chain Filter in the context of a spring boot library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm developing a library that introduces a new authentication filter, that should be used in the spring-security chain

I know I can add the filter via something like:

```java
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
class AmazingSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
    // filter bean
    @Autowired 
    private MyFilter myFilter;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            // ... bunch of requirements per path
            // ... or ignore path "/bla"
            // etc.
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
        
        http.addFilterBefore(myFilter.getFilter(), 
            AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);
    }
}
```

However, this wouldn't work alongside a user defined config. Really, I want to be configuring this bean within my library AutoConfigure class, that's triggered by the spring factories.

Looking around online, I see examples where they extend the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class themselves, and have the user extend this [new config](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/adapters/oidc/spring-security/src/main/java/org/keycloak/adapters/springsecurity/config/KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java#L112-L130). But I don't know if this blocks a user from doing something else, and it also relies on the user first calling `super.configure(http)` to have the filter loaded.

What's the correct way here?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to configure my own `http` configuration by fiddling with the invocation order of the beans within the autoconfiguration

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class)
// Two annotations below ensure that this is not the only WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter,
// as it might otherwise disable security for the rest of the application

// The Order ensures that Spring default which uses ConditionalOnMissingBean is still configured before this class
@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ConditionalOnBean(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.class)
class LibraryFooSecurityConfig {

  @RequiredArgsConstructor
  @Configuration
  @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
  class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // autowired in from elsewhere in the autoconfig
    private final MyFilter filter;

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
          .addFilterBefore(filter,
              AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class);
    }
  }
}
```

This allows a user-defined security config to extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and apply their own rules, while still allowing our library to add it's own items *after* that of the actual spring-boot application